# Paypal refund from 2 different accounts

Tags: paypal

I'm trying a refund for a paypal transaction from 2 different  accounts.  Is there an API to refund a transaction by charging 50% from my account and the rest 50% from a different acc?

Answer (score 0):

If this wasn't a Chained Payment (2 recipients) then you would have to have two transaction IDs to do two refunds.